# Uploading Image to SharePoint from PowerApps via Flow

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

As the title says.. I'm building a power app that uploads an image to a sharepoint directory.

Following [this blog](http://www.techmikael.com/2017/05/an-even-more-clever-workaround-for.html#comment-form) I was able to successfully upload an image that was captured by a Camera Control.

However, I would like to do the same thing but with an 'Add Picture' Control.

My PowerApp function for doing this is

```
ClearCollect(PictureCollection2, AddMediaButton2.Media);
MediaToSharePoint.Run("test.png", First(PictureCollection2).Value)
```

I add the media to a collection, then Run a Flow with the value. This value is a form of a URL that contains the image stored as a blob. Here's an example of the value that gets passed to the Flow

```
blob:https://create.powerapps.com/79d7f767-4dff-448d-87ec-b3d2f7cdf27d
```

The flow has two steps; a PowerApp connector and a Share Point Create File

The flow is failing on the second step with a 'Bad Request' error.

**Has anyone been able to upload an image to Sharepoint via an 'Add Picture' control?**

Any help would be appreciated, let me know if there are any more details I should provide.

Comment: "Add Image" control has different format than captured images. The team is aware that no easy way to do this flow yet. You can go to the forum up-voting posts like [this one](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Ideas/Upload-File-to-Cloud-OneDrive-Sharepoint/idi-p/26436) , add comments about your case, etc. This will help confirm the importance of the feature and bring it to live sooner potentially.

Comment: @user10199063 For what it's worth, I voted for that idea. Also, I ended up using their (relatively) new feature of uploading an image straight to Azure Blob storage, it worked really well.

Comment: Solution using a custom connector here -> https://johnliu.net/blog/2017/7/building-non-json-webservices-with-flow

Comment: There is a solution to do it using a custom connector (here -> http://johnliu.net/blog/2017/7/building-non-json-webservices-with-flow). But, since Microsoft has recently changed the license policies for PowerApps and for using custom connectors you need at least paid Plan 1 (7$/mo) for all your Powerapps users. This is much too expensive for us.
So, we are still looking for a solution without using of custom connectors. 
Are there any other solutions for this?
Except using Onedrive+Excel (does not work well) and Azure Blob Storage (stil too expensive)

Comment: See https://www.powerapps911.com/post/how-to-use-power-apps-to-upload-a-file if you would like to upload arbitrary files to a SharePoint Document library.

Answer (score 2):

We were able to solve the problem by saving pictures to a SharePoint List.

Here are useful links explaining the solution.

- ["Save Attachments to SharePoint List using PowerApps" (YouTube Video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxc3nhgostQ)
- ["Add attachments to SharePoint lists" (Blog Post)](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/add-attachments-to-sharepoint-lists/)
- ["Showing List Attachments in a gallery" (Forum Thread)](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Creating-Apps/Showing-List-Attachments-in-a-gallery/m-p/82804#M875)

It's working!